# Angular watch asynch data from factory

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, watch

I have a service to get my data async and set a reference in the controller:

```
$scope.myData = 0;
$scope.myData = MyService.getData();
```

Now I need to detect if myData is changed. I tried:

```
$scope.$watch("myData", function (newValue, oldValue) {
   console.log($scope.myData);
});
```

But it called only once and not after the async stuff is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` function is only called once.

`$watch` also accepts a function as first parameter. (See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)). Then you can get the data in that function. The returned value will be available in the `$watch` callback.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/uuLwrjur/).

It's a simple counter example to simulate an async. function.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .factory('dataService', dataService)
 .controller('mainController', MainController);
  
  
function dataService($interval) {
 var intPromise;
  var factory = {
   counter: 0,
   start: function() {
     if (angular.isUndefined(intPromise)) {
       intPromise = $interval(factory.run, 1000);
      }
    },
    run: function() {
     factory.counter++;
    },
    getCounter: function() {
     return factory.counter;
    }
  };
  
  return factory;
}

function MainController($scope, dataService) {
 $scope.debug = [];
  dataService.start();
  
 $scope.$watch(function() {
   //return dataService.getCounter();
    return dataService.counter;
  }, function(newValue) {
   $scope.debug.push("counter changed: " + newValue); 
  }); //,true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="info in debug">{{info}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```